# Align Div at bottom on main Div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs, one inside the other and I would like the small div to be aligned at the buttom of the main div.

Here's my code so far. Currently, the button is at the top of main div, instead I want it positioned at the bottom. Any help would be appreciated.

```
.vertical_banner {
    border: 1px solid #E9E3DD;
    float: left;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 4px 2px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 117px;
}

#bottom_link{
 vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Here's how I've been trying to use it, but as you can see I'm still new to CSS :)

```
<div class="vertical_banner">
    <div id="bottom_link">
         <input type="submit" value="Continue">
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Modify your CSS like this:

```css
.vertical_banner {
    border: 1px solid #E9E3DD;
    float: left;
    height: 210px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 4px 2px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 117px;
    position:relative;
}

#bottom_link{
   position:absolute;                  /* added */
   bottom:0;                           /* added */
   left:0;                           /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical_banner">
    <div id="bottom_link">
         <input type="submit" value="Continue">
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I still find this quite useful even after over a year on. Nice, work :)

Answer (score 10):

Give your parent div `position: relative`, then give your child div `position: absolute`, this will absolute position the div inside of its parent, then you can give the child `bottom: 0px;`

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PGMqs/1/

Answer (score 5):

This isn't really possible in HTML unless you use absolute positioning or javascript. So one solution would be to give this CSS to #bottom_link:

```
#bottom_link {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Otherwise you'd have to use some javascript. Here's a jQuery block that should do the trick, depending on the simplicity of the page.

```
$('#bottom_link').css({
    position: 'relative',
    top: $(this).parent().height() - $(this).height()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you'll need absolute position

```
.vertical_banner {position:relative;}
#bottom_link{position:absolute; bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
#b {
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: -moz-inline-flex;
display: inline-flex;

-webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
-moz-flex-flow: row nowrap;
flex-flow: row nowrap;

-webkit-align-items: flex-end;
-moz-align-items: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;}
```

Here's a JSFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7FGKN/.

Comment: When providing answers, please take the time to explain why your answer has been provided, and why it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to add a `margin-top: auto` and `margin-bottom: 0`. This tells the margin top to fill in the missing space.

Comment: Thanks @beeeliu for your input. Hopefully someone else will find this your suggest useful.