# align div in the bottom of another div using css

Tags: css, html

I want to align the `DIV c` in the bottom of the `DIV b` not `DIV a`

```
<div id="a">
   <div id="b">
        <div id="c">
              Div c
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301720/align-div-at-bottom-on-main-div

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This should work:

```
#b {
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

The trick is `position: relative;` on the parent element. Without that, `#c` will float away to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 8):

It will take `div#c` out of the flow of the document. It may not be perfect, but you can do something like the following:

```
#b {
  position: relative;
}

#c {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Click in this link, maybe it can help you

```
#b {
display: -webkit-inline-flex;
display: -moz-inline-flex;
display: inline-flex;

-webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
-moz-flex-flow: row nowrap;
flex-flow: row nowrap;

-webkit-align-items: flex-end;
-moz-align-items: flex-end;
align-items: flex-end;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/7FGKN/

Comment: Did you change it in the link? Nothing of the kind is there.