# How to align div at the bottom of another div (it's floating up..)

Tags: alignment

I can't figure out how to bottom-align the **WHITE "LIKE" DIV** div in this illustration, so it appears at the very bottom of the comment, instead of floating up, when the user only wrote a few lines in his post.

Need advise on either CSS or HTML approach to this, depending on which will do the job.

![Floating div](https://images.vfl.ru/ii/1409154367/984280d6/6144732.png
)
[image: floating div]

http://bibelkristna.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=12  has some likes. 
In order to see the likes, use  thastrom/test123

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer obtain from similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935575/align-div-in-the-bottom-of-another-div-using-css), that was previous asked.

```
#b {
    position: relative;
}

#c {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

The trick is position: relative; on the parent element. Without that, #c will float away to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I'll have a go! Thank you! The other answer I found didn't work, or I misunderstood it. Tables are a bad idea, right?

Comment: Bob's answer is right but I can't give him any points yet due to being a newbie here.