# textarea fixed in the bottom of div - CSS

Tags: css

I want to put a textarea in the bottom of a div (and fixed there):

```
<div id=msg>

 <div id=content>
     aaaaaaaannnnnnnnnn<br>
     aaaaaaaannnnnnnnnn<br>
     aaaaaaaannnnnnnnnn<br>
 </div>

 <div id=text>
  <textarea></textarea>
 </div>

</div>
```

css

```
#msg{
 width:60%;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
}
#content{
overflow-y: auto;
}
#text{
 bottom:0;
position:fixed;
}
```

why bottom:0 not working?
http://jsfiddle.net/mu1tynax/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align content of a div to the bottom with css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/585945/how-to-align-content-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-with-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
position:relative;
```

to #msg

and

```
position:absolute;
```

to #text

I've updated the JSFiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/mu1tynax/5/

credits to: [Align Div at bottom on main Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301720/align-div-at-bottom-on-main-div)

Answer (score 1):

In your fiddle, you missed the `position: fixed`.  However, note that fixed positioning is relative to the body, not to the relative parent div.

Insert the position in your fiddle and it works.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set position to absolute in your "text" div, but also set the position to relative in the parent div. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hc2d59d/)

```
#msg{
 width:60%;
 height:500px;
 float:left;
 background-color:#fff;
 border:1px solid #000;
 overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#text{
    position: absolute;
 bottom:0;
}
```

More info on positioning elements (absolute) here:  https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: @TheOddGuy if I needed to copy and paste your answer, then I should be fired from my job.  This is a very simple solution.